# Calculating the age of a person using two NSDates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, time, nsdate

My class representing a person has a method to calculate that person's age:

```
@interface Student : NSObject

@property (strong) NSDate *dob;

// This method will work out the person's age in calendar years
- (NSDateComponents*)ageCalculation:(NSDate*)dob;
```

Here is the class implementation file

```
@implementation Student

- (NSDateComponents*)ageCalculation:(NSDate*)dob {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSCalendarUnit units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units 
                                               fromDate:dob 
                                                 toDate:now   
                                                options:0];
    return components;
}

@end
```

I'm not sure that I'm doing this right, though:

```
Student *student1 = [[Student alloc] init];
[student1 setDob:aDateOfBirth];
NSDateComponents *ageComponents = [student1 ageCalculation:aDateOfBirth];
```

What should I do with the result of this method? How can I make `ageCalculation:` use the date I already set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of things that can be noted. First of all, the code for computing the age is fine, except that I don't understand why you return `NSDateComponents` instead of just the age in years.

Here's how I would do it

```
- (NSInteger)age {
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *ageComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                                       components:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                       fromDate:self.dob
                                       toDate:today
                                       options:0];
    return ageComponents.year;
}
```

You are interested only in the `year` component, so return it instead of `NSDateComponents`. Using `self.dob` instead of an argument gets the date you set earlier.

Comment: Thank you so much I adjusted my code given your recommendations and it is now working perfectly. I really appreciated your help as I was completely stuck. I had no idea how complicated a simple age calculation could be and to be able to call it as a method, given the differences in calendars and leap years etc it now makes sense that it would not be so easy!

Comment: Gabriele, I'm editing your very thorough answer to make it less localized to this user's particular code after it's been used [as a dupe target](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24248088). I sincerely hope this does not offend!

Comment: @JoshCaswell no offense taken. I agree both answer and question are more general now, thanks for the effort. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is tested solution, After long time I get a chance to work with Objective C and trying to find age from date of birth then I write this solution, Hopefully this help someone

```
 Call this Function as : [self getAge:datePicker.date]

- (NSString *)getAge:(NSDate *)dateOfBirth {
    NSInteger years;
    NSInteger months;
    NSInteger days;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay;

    NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:dateOfBirth toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    years = [dateComponent year];
    months = [dateComponent month];
    days = [dateComponent day];

    NSString *ageStr = [[NSString alloc]init];

    if (years > 0) {
        if (years > 1) {
            ageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld years",years];
        }
        else {
            ageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld year",years];
        }
    }

    if (months > 0) {
        if (months > 1) {
            if(![ageStr isEqualToString:@""]) {
                ageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ld months",ageStr,months];
            }
            else {
                ageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld months",months];
            }
        }
        else {
            if(![ageStr isEqualToString:@""]) {
                ageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ld month",ageStr,months];
            }
            else {
                ageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld month",months];
            }
        }
    }

    if (days > 0) {
        if (days > 1) {
            if(![ageStr isEqualToString:@""]) {
                ageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ld days",ageStr,days];
            }
            else {
                ageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld days",days];
            }
        }
        else {
            if(![ageStr isEqualToString:@""]) {
                ageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ld day",ageStr,days];
            }
            else {
                ageStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld day",days];
            }
        }
    }
    return ageStr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just created a simple method that returns the age in years as a string.

```
-(NSString *) getAge:(NSDate *)dateOfBirth {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierIndian];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:dateOfBirth
                                                 toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                options:0];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",components.year];
    }
```

**NOTE**

1. This uses **Indian Calendar** - change it if u wish.
2. To call **`NSString *yearsOldinString = [self getAge:dateOfBirth];`**, where dateOfBirth represents person's date of birth in NSDate format.

Comment: Why post a duplicate answer 2.5 years after the original answer?

Comment: Agreed that the original answer works perfectly! But I wouldnt consider this as a duplicate as it returns the answer in string. NSDate and NSString are two different things

Comment: If the only difference is converting the number of years into a string at the end of doing the exact same calculation, then I call that a duplicate. That one trivial difference certainly isn't worth posting an answer for. Especially years later on a closed question.

Comment: I value what you say, You're indeed right in saying im doing the same thing why write it again. :) I hope down the years it'll help someone